# CSS dinâmico em backgorund-color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou criando uma grid de cards e cada card pode ter até três background-color diferentes, existe alguma forma de deixar essa cor dinâmica? Ao invés de criar três classes iguais no html, mudando apenas a cor de cada.

[image: Exemplo_card]

```css
 .card_head {
 
  padding: 25px;
  background-color:#FE5959;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  float: left;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="card_head"></div>
```

Comment: Para você fazer isso precisará usar o JavaScript e trocar a classe com cor diferente para cada uma.

Comment: cria uma classe para o card e três classes para as cores de fundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso, incluindo colocar um atributo `style="background-color: ;"` direto na tag. Mas só com CSS de uma forma mais "sofisticada" seria usando `CSS Variables`. Com isso vc um *override* para a cor dependendo do caso... *(Essa é uma abordagem semelhante a usada por diversos Design Systems como o Bootstrap por exemplo)*

```css
/* suas cores pré definidas */ 
.alerta {
  --cor: red;
}
.sucesso {
  --cor: green;
}

.card_head {
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  
  background-color: var(--cor); /* só tem um background-color */
}
```

```html
<div class="card_head alerta"></div>

<div class="card_head sucesso"></div>

<!-- Definido a --cor direto na tag -->

<div class="card_head" style="--cor: gold"></div>
```

Comment: Legal, cara! Fiz assim mesmo com algumas mudanças e deu certo aqui. Valeu demais.

Comment: @Ozzott que massa que te serviu ai! Cara se alguma das resposta resolveu o problema considere marca-la como aceita, basta clicar nesse ícone ✔︎ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta que vc escolher. Assim a sua pergunta não fica em aberto mesmo já tendo sido resolvida ;)

Answer (score 2):

Uma das alternativas para não criar 3 classes iguais é criar classes CSS que são aplicadas apenas quando utilizadas em conjunto com `.card_head`. Cada classe dessas levará apenas o `background-color`.

```css
.card_head {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color:#FE5959;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  float: left; 
}

.card_head.cor1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.card_head.cor2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.card_head.cor3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card_head cor1">Lorem</div>
<div class="card_head cor2">Lorem</div>
<div class="card_head cor3">Lorem</div>
```

Outra forma é alterar o background através de JavaScript mas não entendi se isto seria uma solução para o seu cenário. De qualquer forma segue um exemplo:

```js
function alterar() {
  document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

```css
 .card_head {
      padding: 25px;
      background-color:#FE5959;
      max-width: 30px;
      max-height: 30px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 15px;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; 
      align-items: center; 
      float: left; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="card_head">Lorem</div>
<button onclick="alterar()">Alterar cor</button>
```

Comment: Com o javascript não daria certo, mas de qualquer forma valeu demais!